# SQL Stored Procedure WHERE CLAUSE Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and I cant work out how the string is meant to be built up.

The SQL statement works fine when I do not have a variable in there so it is definitely the way I am writing it in. I am just a beginner so unsure about the syntax.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SLINVOICE]
@varCURRENCY AS VARCHAR(3)

AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT  dbo.invmaster.InvNumber

              FROM dbo.invmaster INNER JOIN dbo.invdetail ON dbo.invmaster.INVMasterID = dbo.invdetail.INVMasterID 
              INNER JOIN dbo.Company ON dbo.invmaster.InvCompanyID = dbo.Company.CompanyID

              WHERE dbo.InvMaster.InvCurrency = '' + @varCURRENCY + ''
              AND dbo.invmaster.DocType <> ''MC''
              ORDER BY dbo.invmaster.InvNumber ASC;';


EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

The @varCURRENCY does not give me an error when i execute. But it does not work either when i pass it through a parameter.

Please let me know if you can see what the issue is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: close the quote before variable and open the quote after variable.

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is ending up like this:

```
WHERE   dbo.InvMaster.InvCurrency = '@varCURRENCY'
```

So you are not looking for the value of the parameter, you are looking for `@Currency`, I am not sure why you are using Dynamic SQL, the following should work fine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SLINVOICE] @varCURRENCY AS VARCHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  dbo.invmaster.InvNumber
    FROM dbo.invmaster 
        INNER JOIN dbo.invdetail 
            ON dbo.invmaster.INVMasterID = dbo.invdetail.INVMasterID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Company 
            ON dbo.invmaster.InvCompanyID = dbo.Company.CompanyID
    WHERE dbo.InvMaster.InvCurrency = @varCURRENCY
    AND dbo.invmaster.DocType <> 'MC'
    ORDER BY dbo.invmaster.InvNumber ASC;

END
```

If you need Dynamic SQL for some other reason you can use the following to pass `@varCURRENCY` as a parameter to `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT  dbo.invmaster.InvNumber

              FROM dbo.invmaster INNER JOIN dbo.invdetail ON dbo.invmaster.INVMasterID = dbo.invdetail.INVMasterID 
              INNER JOIN dbo.Company ON dbo.invmaster.InvCompanyID = dbo.Company.CompanyID

              WHERE dbo.InvMaster.InvCurrency = @varCURRENCY 
              AND dbo.invmaster.DocType <> ''MC''
              ORDER BY dbo.invmaster.InvNumber ASC;';


EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@varCURRENCY VARCHAR(3)', @varCURRENCY;
```

Comment: Wow thanks GarethD, I forgot to explain that I am using the Dynamic SQL because I am pass the parameter through from Access VBA.
Can you explain why I need to put 

'N'@varCURRENCY VARCHAR(3)', @varCURRENCY; '

this part of the code in at the end? I dont understand why but it works now!

Comment: sp_executesql executes the sql in the same session, but a different scope to the calling code, therefore has no knowledge of the parameter definition of `@varCurrency`, you need to pass the parameter definition to the same scope that the sql is being executed in.

Comment: I don't know how calling this from Access VBA would mean you need dynamic SQL. You should be fine with the procedure definition I have posted above that does not use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is then. when would a dynamic SQL be used?

Comment: Also is it possible to use mulitple parameters and not just @VarCurrency? I tried to add more but it errored out...

Comment: To pass more than one parameter, you would need something like `EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@varCURRENCY VARCHAR(3), @p2 INT', @varCURRENCY, @p2;`, i.e. include all definitions in the same string, then pass the parameters separated by a comma (in the same order they are declared).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55987/discussion-between-cocojay-and-garethd).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a variable to an `sp_executesql` context, you need to pass it as a parameter.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          @sql,
          N'@varCurrency varchar(3)',
          @varcurrency= @varCurrency;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx

Although why you don't just use

```
select ...  where dbo.InvMaster.InvCurrency = @varCURRENCY
```

instead of the executesql is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `@varCURRENCY` as a parameter, Remove extra `'` from your Sp.

```
WHERE dbo.InvMaster.InvCurrency = ' + @varCURRENCY + '
```

Or do not use dynamic query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SLINVOICE]
@varCURRENCY AS VARCHAR(3)

AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT  dbo.invmaster.InvNumber

              FROM dbo.invmaster INNER JOIN dbo.invdetail ON dbo.invmaster.INVMasterID = dbo.invdetail.INVMasterID 
              INNER JOIN dbo.Company ON dbo.invmaster.InvCompanyID = dbo.Company.CompanyID

              WHERE dbo.InvMaster.InvCurrency =  @varCURRENCY 
              AND dbo.invmaster.DocType <> 'MC'
              ORDER BY dbo.invmaster.InvNumber ASC;
```